# Console window - programmatic command code (wParam of WM_COMMAND)

Tags: windows, windows-console

I find it very interesting when I can control a console window with my C#/C++ program.

According to this post: [Programmatically Paste Clipboard Text to a CMD Window (C# or C++)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bill/2012/06/09/programmatically-paste-clipboard-text-to-a-cmd-window-c-or-c/), we can execute paste command for a console with this code

```
 // hwnd is the window handle of a console window
 SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 0xfff1, 0);
```

So 0xfff1 is the command (wParam) for Paste. But I see that there are several useful commands:

1. Copy
2. Select All
3. Paste ---> 0xfff1
4. Execute command (When you press Enter to execute a cmd command)
5. [Clear current input](https://superuser.com/a/397191/525666) (when you press Esc)
6. Ctrl + C command (you know what that is, not copy btw)

If I have the execute command, then I can combine paste & execute to programmatically execute a command in a console from my software. Or if I know "Select All" & "Copy", I can programmatically copy the content of the console. 
[image: console]
So does anyone know the programmatic command code (wParam) of the command above? Especially the execute command.

Comment: Have you tried to paste the command with an ending CRLF?

Comment: For what it's worth, the menu command IDs can easily be read from the console host DLL multi-language user interface resource file (e.g. "en-us\ConhostV2.dll.mui"). In order of ID, the menu items are copy (0xfff0), paste (0xfff1), mark (0xfff2), scroll (0xfff3), find (0xfff4), and select all (0xfff5).

Comment: @MCND - Thank you, so paste the `Environment.NewLine //C#` equal run command, I should have known it :D
@eryksun - Thank you, you're right, I've tried: select all & copy, it works.